# building issue of Android 7.0

Tags: android, c++

When I am buiding Android7.0 I got this kind of error. Could you please help me how to solve it.

```
frameworks/av/services/audioflinger/AudioMixer.cpp:790: error: undefined reference to 
    'android::AudioResampler::create(audio_format_t, int, int, android::AudioResampler::src_quality)'
frameworks/av/services/audioflinger/AudioMixer.cpp:790: error: undefined reference to
    'android::AudioResampler::create(audio_format_t, int, int, android::AudioResampler::src_quality)'
frameworks/av/services/audioflinger/Threads.cpp:6950: error: undefined reference to
    'android::AudioResampler::create(audio_format_t, int, int, android::AudioResampler::src_quality)'
```

Comment: You have not supplied enough information. Are you using the NDK? and if so are your files in the exact correct package directory and are they being loaded properly

Comment: I have downloaded the source code from Android Source.com. I am using Android NDK. I have gone through that directory but still iam not getting

Comment: It is likely a path issue, see https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk for example projects. Once you have one working you can start to identify where your issue is. Goodluck.

Comment: I am not getting I have gone through that link . It has not helped to solve the issue

Comment: There is not enough information to solve your issue. You only supply your error and version of Android. I need to see how you are using the NDK, where you include it, how you reference the JNIs and your folder structure that ecompasses the C files or packaged binaries to even begin helping. Then I would need to see where the AudioMixer files are at in your package structure and where you load them into your project. Far too many variables missing to help you.